# Who has copied or reimplemented Ripple?

Tags: ripple

There have been almost an infinite amount of Bitcoin clones, but I have yet to see a Ripple clone or a Peercoin clone for that matter.  I'd include Nextcoin, but I don't think the full source has been released yet.

Is this correct?  If so, why not?

Ripple seems the most logical to clone because of the superiority of the code, and all one need do is generate a new genesis and checkpoint etc.

Are there a ton of Bitcoin clones because it has the largest market cap, and all want to get a piece, or does all of the undeserved bad rap that comes with Ripple repel clones?  That last logic doesn't hold much water when it comes to Peercoin.  Or is it harder to attract miners for Ripple because of the fee structure?

This makes no sense to me.  Why haven't the other major coins been cloned into oblivion like Bitcon?

Comment: See https://ripple.com/wiki/Forks

Comment: Also, your comments about mining doesn't make sense to me. Ripple has no mining by design. Those looking to make an alt-coin for the purpose of a pre-mine get-rich-quick-scheme would instead just create a new "scam" IOU within Ripple. Several people have tried this but so far no one has given them any value (worth mentioning) for the worthless IOUs they try and promote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [list of forks](https://ripple.com/wiki/Forks) on the Ripple wiki. It currently lists four projects.

As to why there are not more, any answer will by necessity be opinion based which tends to be not appropriate on a StackExchange site. But my answer would be that, as you say, producing an identical fork is trivial to do but also useless. The value of system like Ripple comes from [network effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network%5feffect) that a clone would lack. The only reason rational people would consider a using a fork would be if it had some important new feature (hard, lots of work) or if the existing implementation had some serious actual or perceived flawed that the fork did not (including possibly just the perceived control a specific entity may have on the network). For many issues people appear to have with Ripple, instead of forking it makes much more sense to work towards having a set of validators with a robust set of [UNL](https://ripple.com/wiki/UNL) entries that possibly exclude Ripple Labs and additional non-Ripple Labs contributors to the code base.